# Alternating Series Convergence / Divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, divergent-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ - I know this doesn't converge and I want to prove it. I am using the null sequence test as the limit as $n$ tends to $\infty$ of $(-1)^n$ doesn't equal 0 which I am trying to prove.

$1.$ First I thought I could let $a_n := (-1)^n$ and note that the two subsequences $a_{
2k}$ and $a_{2k-1}$ have two distinct limits where $k$ is a natural number, them being $1$ and $-1$, so $a_n$ clearly diverges. Hence, if it diverges it doesn't converge to $0$, meaning the series diverges by null sequence test. $\square$

$2.$ Assume for sake of contradiction that $a_n = (-1)^n$ converges to a limit $l$ where $l$ is a real number. Let $\epsilon = 1$. Now, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $|(-1)^n-l|<1$.

Note that when $n$ is even, $(-1)^n = 1$, so we have $|1-l| < 1$. When $n$ is odd, we have $|-1-l| < 1$. Now $2 = |1-l + 1+l| <= |1-l| + |1+l| = |1-l| + |-1-l| < 1 + 1 = 2$, so $2<2$ which is a contradiction. Hence, $a_n$ diverges so doesn't converge to $0$, meaning the series diverges by null sequence test. $\square$

Comment: Convergence of the series is a convergence of partial sum, not element.

Comment: @openspace Okay, how is that relevant here ? For $2$, I know that the sequence tending to $0$ is necessary for series convergence, which is why I proved that the sequence does not converge to $0$

Comment: Note that $a_n \to 0$ is equivalent to $|a_n| \to 0$.

Comment: @MartinR ohhhh yeah I remember that. That would make the question a lot easier. Because I didn’t notice that I’ll stick with my proof $1$ but I’ll keep what you said in mind for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikita, both of your ideas look good. Either one on its own is sufficient to show that the sequence diverges, and thus the series diverges. Just a couple little things on the writing:

1. In the first one, I would replace "Hence, if it diverges" with "Hence, *since* it diverges", since you just concluded in the previous sentence that it does in fact diverge.
2. In the second one, it's a bit confusing that you say "Let $\epsilon = 1$" and then continue with "Now, for all $\epsilon > 0$". Once you fix your $\epsilon$, you don't want to reassign it to something else. Your argument still makes perfect sense though if you just say "Let $\epsilon = 1$. Then there exists a natural number $N$ ..." If you think the person reading your proof will be really pedantic about it, then you could throw in "Let $\epsilon = 1$. Then, since $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ ..."

Hope this helps!

EDIT: If we want to consider the problem directly rather than showing that the sequence $a_n$ doesn't converge (which is sufficient), then we can directly observe that the partial sums don't converge since for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $$\left|\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} (-1)^n\right) - \left(\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\right)\right| = |(-1)^{N+1}| = 1,$$
so the sequence of partial sums is not Cauchy, and therefore does not converge.

Comment: $1$ Understood. $2$ Yeah that is sloppy I agree, I'll fix it. Thanks for your help, I feel like $1$ is better because it's simpler so I will use that argument.

Comment: No problem Nikita! I agree that 1 is simple and really easy to understand.

Comment: If the sequence doesn't converge, it's incorrect to say it diverges right because you can only assume that for a series. So I would have to say that since $a_n$ doesn't converge to a real number that it doesn't converge to $0$....

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at. One rule for series is that if $a_n \not\rightarrow 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is not well-defined. This is what I thought you were referring to when saying "null sequence test", but maybe I misunderstood

Comment: yeah perfect, that’s what I meant